# Constructing different default values for different types in a union?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a tagged union like this

```
type FieldValue = 
   | { type: “multiple-choice”, content: string[] }
   | { type: “text”, content: string }
```

And I’d like to have a “smart constructur” function

```
function default<T extends FieldValue>(): T {
    ...
}
```

Which would return either

```
{ type: “multiple-choice”, content: [] }
```

Or

```
{ type: “text”, content: “” }
```

Based on the type T. Now, I know I can’t access generic types at runtime, but maybe there’s a better way to go about this altogether (interfaces? Conditional types? Classes?).

Is there any way I can spare myself the work of writing defaultText and defaultMultipleChoice by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go other way around, see if this helps:

```js
const MultipleChoice = {
  type: 'multiple-choice' as const,
  content: [] as string[]
}

const SingleChoice = {
  type: 'text' as const,
  content: ''
}

type MultipleChoice = typeof MultipleChoice
type SingleChoice = typeof SingleChoice

type FieldValue = MultipleChoice | SingleChoice
```